# Can someone please explain how this recursion function works?

Tags: java

I just started recursion and happened across a function similar to this, so I adapted it to the question on my homework:

```
public int getRSquare(int n){
    if(n==0){
        return 1;
    }
    return getRSquare(n-1)*n;
}
```

So when n=5, it returns 120, which is correct, this method outputs the factorial of n. But I don't understand WHY. Doesn't n eventually reach 0, so shouldn't it return 1, not 120? This is java btw, just in case that's needed

Comment: I remember the joke my professor told me around 15 years ago: "to understand recursion, you first need to understand recursion"

Comment: It returns 1 only when n == 0.

When n == 1 it returns 1*1 (the first 1 is getRSquare(n-1)).  
When n == 2 it returns the same thing as before multiplied by 2, that is 1*1*2.  
When n == 3 it returns the same thing as before, multiplied by 3, that is 1*1*2*3.
And so on...

Everytime it runs `getRSquare(n-1)*n;` the function starts again, but it doesn't forget that it needs to run the `*n` part afterwards. That's why it ends up generating a long sequence of multiplications. How does the computer rebember all those pending operations? Because it puts them on a *stack*.

Comment: What I have done, is replied to the question for which this question has been marked as a duplicate. Click on the link for that question and find my response at the end. I hate it when StackOverflow zealots make life hard for new users.

Comment: @AndrewS Feel free to cast a reopen vote to the question. Imo it is a direct duplicate of linked question. It would help the reopen process if you explain why you think it is not.

Comment: Zabuzard, thank you for your fast response. I wanted to but did not see a user interface feature on my screen for that. Maybe I do not have enough points.

Answer (score 0):

on the return value `n` is updated each time when the method is called. 5-1=4-1=3-1=2-1=2-1=0.
When `n` is 0 the method stop.

Comment: I get why it stops now, but I still don't understand why it adds them all up? If n==0, it should return ONLY 1 right? Not add up the previous values alongside it

Comment: See my comment above. It returns 1 but there's a `*n` operation that runs after returning.